# how to add gradient fill to path in svg?

Tags: svg, gradient, fill

so I was trying really hard to learn svg and following all the tutorials and everything and the only thing I can't seem to figure out is how to make a path and fill the path with a gradient, while keeping all the other shapes and information in the image. really hope someone knows how to fix this. really, would be so much help if you could help me out here.

Comment: thnks, but why not answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:00ff43;" />
    <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:f9fd27;" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:f20000;" />
  </linearGradient>
</defs>

<polyline points="50,350 60,340 70,345" filter="url(#black-glow)" style="fill:none;" stroke="url(#grad1)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" />
```

similar with path